# Visual Paradigm: How to activate community edition on a PC without Internet Connection

Tags: uml

I installed visual paradigm community edition on my PC. My PC does NOT have internet connection. After 30 days of use, its asking for my name and email id on launch so that it can send me community edition activation code on my email.

However, I do not have internet connection so its not able to proceed and giving error message that server cannot be reached.

How do I work around this issue.
Even skip option is not present.

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: Stupid question, if you do not have an internet connection, how are you able to post on here? Are you able to share the internet connection temporarily to your PC to activate it?

Comment: do you think i will be simply asking this question if I DO have internet connection on my PC.. the PC which I work on is  the one not connected to internet.. the one having internet is a public PC , not my personal one.. FYI temporary internet also not possible on my work PC